# AnimatedAlign is not working with Row Flultter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to set animation on my text left to right, using AnimatedAlign. If I wrap my widget with Row, animation getting stop.
here is my sample code

````
static const _alignments = [
    Alignment.topLeft,
    Alignment.topRight,
    Alignment.bottomLeft,
    Alignment.bottomRight,
  ];

  var _index = 0;
  AlignmentGeometry get _alignment => _alignments[_index % _alignments.length];
              
Row(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
   AnimatedAlign(
    alignment: _alignment,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
     child: Text(
      "Aligned Text",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    )),
  ],
 ),
FlatButton(
 color: Colors.purple,
  onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
   _index++;
  });
 },

 child: Icon(
 Icons.play_arrow,
 color: Colors.white,
 size: 36.0,
 ),
)```
````

Comment: Can you share full code of the class